# Convert CSV file to json iterating through columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a csv file looking like this:

```
Question Answer
a           A 
b           NaN
c           NaN
d           B 
e           NaN
f           NaN
```

What I want is to create a dictionary (or json file) such as:

```
[{'answer': 'A', 'questions':'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'answer': 'B', 'questions':'d', 'e', 'f'}]
```

Which is the most efficient way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

We can check `ffill` before `groupby`

```
df.groupby(df.Answer.ffill()).Question.agg(list).reset_index().to_dict('r')
Out[17]: 
[{'Answer': 'A', 'Question': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
 {'Answer': 'B', 'Question': ['d', 'e', 'f']}]
```

Comment: How could I add more elements to my dictionary if needed if they are not in the dataframe?